# Drupal 7: how to redesign, move stuff around, for a content type page?

Tags: views, nodes

If when creating a View, I create a list of a specific content type, let's say Staff. It lists everyone from the Staff content type. I have this setting too: Link to the original piece of content. Then I get a list of content type labels and content type data. How can I rearrange everything? How can I edit the HTML?

I don't want to create a view for a specific content type, I want to redesign (edit HTML) the content type page, example: domain.com/node/5

Comment: That's rather a broad topic - have you read the [Theming Guide](https://drupal.org/documentation/theme)?

Comment: are you asking to have a different page structure for a specific content type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not clear with your questions ,adding some pointers on some assumptions.

Custom Way

1 . If you want to override a node structure for a specific content type

-- You can copy the node.tpl.php to your theme and rename it to node--type.tpl.php. Inside node--type.tpl.php , you will be rearranging the elements.

2 . If you want to override every node,irrespective to any content type.

-- Copy node.tpl.php inside your theme and do the rearrangement of elements.

3 . If you want to override a particular node

-- Copy the node.tpl.php and rename it to node--nodeid.tpl.php and do the rearrangement of elements

Some Helpful Links:

https://drupal.org/node/1089656

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dfwU0WtCuPs

**Remember** to clear the caches after you are done with building of templates.

Using Contrib Module

You can use [panels module](https://drupal.org/project/panels) to override node templates without creating them. panele module will do that for you.

Some Helpful Links:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_VIkE2ZS5oU

Comment: @leonel try [theme developer module](https://drupal.org/project/devel_themer) it will give you clear insight of what templates are responsible to theme a page and alternate overriding options.